# Laravel Ajax Call to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, controller

I am pretty new with `Laravel` and I am having an issue with accessing a specific method in my `Controller`. I am trying to change a Database value (language) based on a dropdown menu.

**settings.profile.blade**

```
<select id="accountLanguage" class="form-control" method="GET">
    <option value="en" {{ ($strLanguage == 'en') ? 'selected = "selected"' : "" }} >English</option>
    <option value="es" {{ ($strLanguage == 'es') ? 'selected = "selected"' : "" }} >Español</option>
    <option value="he" {{ ($strLanguage == 'fr') ? 'selected = "selected"' : "" }} >French</option>
</select>
```

**ProfileController**

```
public function index() {

    $objUser = Auth::User();

    $strLanguage = $objUser->lang;

    return view("application.settings.profile",[
        'objUser' => $objUser,
        'strLanguage' => $strLanguage
    ]); 

}   

// THE METHOD I NEED ACCESS TO
function update( $strLang ) { 

    $objUser = Auth::User();

    // UPDATE LANGUAGE
    $bolUpdated = $objUser->updateLanguage( $strLang );

    // RETURN
    return response()->json( $bolUpdated );
 }
```

**Route**

```
Route::namespace( 'Settings' )->prefix( 'settings' )->group( function () {

    ...

    // PROFILE
    Route::resource( 'profile', 'ProfileController', ['only' => ['index','update']] );
    Route::get('test', 'ProfileController@update');
});
```

**settings.profile.js**

```
function initProfileManager() {

    // GET ELEMENTS
    var domUpdateLanguage = $('#accountLanguage');

    var updateLanguage = function() {

        // MAKE AJAX CALL
        $.ajaxq( {
            // url:'/settings/profile',
            url:'./test',
            method:'GET',
            success: function( bolUpdated ) { 
                if( bolUpdated ) { 
                    alert('OK');
                }   
            },  
            fail: function() {
                alert('NO');
            }   
         }); 
         location.reload();
    };  
    domUpdateLanguage.on( 'change', updateLanguage );
```

The way it currently is, I get this error `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Settings\ProfileController::update(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected`. I understand the error, but not sure how to pass the argument.

If I uncomment the `url` line from the `JS`, I never get into the `update` method and I just end up running `index` twice.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Strange. I tried defining a random value and it would still give me that error. I think you might be right and it is a syntax issue. Can't see why it would happen though.

```
function initProfileManage(strLang) {

    // GET ELEMENTS
    var domUpdateLanguage           = $('#accountLanguage');

    var updateLanguage = function() {

        // MAKE AJAX CALL
        $.ajaxq({
            // url:'/settings/profile',
            url:'./test',
            method:'POST',
            data: { 
                    strLang: newLang,
            }   
            success: function( bolUpdated ) { 
                if( bolUpdated ) { 
                    alert('OK');
                }   
            },  
            fail: function() {
                alert('NO');
            }   
         }); 
         location.reload();
    };  

    // UPATE LANGUAGE EVENT
    domUpdateLanguage.on( 'change', updateLanguage );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete answer to your question

**Use a POST request instead of GET**

Because you are updating the user's language it's more secure to use a POST request

```
// MAKE AJAX CALL
$.ajax( {
    // url:'/settings/profile',
    url:'./test',
    method:'POST',
    data: {
       strLang: newLang
    },
    success: function( bolUpdated ) { 
        if( bolUpdated ) { 
            alert('OK');
        }   
    },  
    fail: function() {
        alert('NO');
    }   
});
```

and don't forget to pass the strLang in your post request via the data attribute.

**Protect against CSRF attacks**

Store the csrf token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Automatically add the token to all request headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**Create a route to handle your ajax request:**

```
Route::post('test', 'ProfileController@update');
```

**Get strLang via the $request object in your controller:**

```
function update( $request ) { 

    $objUser = Auth::User();

    // UPDATE LANGUAGE
    $bolUpdated = $objUser->updateLanguage( $request->strLang );

    // RETURN
    return response()->json( $bolUpdated );
}
```

If you are using HTML5, your settings.profile.blade should look like this:

```
<select id="accountLanguage" class="form-control" method="GET">
    <option value="en" {{ ($strLanguage == 'en') ? 'selected' : '' }} >English</option>
    <option value="es" {{ ($strLanguage == 'es') ? 'selected' : '' }} >Español</option>
    <option value="he" {{ ($strLanguage == 'fr') ? 'selected' : '' }} >French</option>
</select>
```

In your index method, $objUser already contains the lang property

```
public function index() {

    $objUser = Auth::User();

    return view("application.settings.profile",[
        'objUser' => $objUser
    ]); 

}
```

Getting the new lang from select element:

```
$('#accountLanguage').change(function () {
     initProfileManager(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. I changed to your suggestions and it seems like I am getting an error on the `js` file. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for the `strLang: newLang` part. I think it might be related to what you said about passing the strLang in the post request via the data attribute?

Comment: Yes , You have to get the new Lang from an input for axample. Ex: `var newLang = $('#inputId').val();` and then pass it to data object

Comment: Do I pass it from the `blade`?

Comment: All I have in the `blade` is `$(document).ready(function(){ initProfileManager();` in the bottom of the page.

Comment: What you are updating here is the user lang, so when the user select  another lang, you should call `initProfileManager` with the selected lang in parameter: Ex `initProfileManager(this.value);`

Comment: I just tried this. `blade` - `initProfileManager('en')` and on the `js` - `function initProfileManage(strLang)`. It still gives me the same error..

Comment: In your AJAX method check if there is a missing comma at the end of data attribute

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to:

```
Route::post('test', 'ProfileController@update');
```

and your ajax object:

```
method:'POST',
```

You have to actually pass $strLang somehow, too (since the update() method expects this, as the error message states).

Oh, and you really don't need the method attribute in your select HTML ;)

Comment: Why POST? It leads to `csrf` excluding issue. Too complex.

Comment: Because Laravel makes it pretty easy to get by these issues by a single initial ajaxSetup(). And for the methods: If you go by "the standards", you end up with: UPDATE always as POST or PUT.

Answer (score 1):

You should define language in the route

```
Route::get('test/{strLang}', 'ProfileController@update');`
```

as well as pass it as a variable to the url in js code: `'/test/' + strLang`