# Getting "too few arguments passed to function" when submitting a Laravel form with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm building a form inside a Bootstrap modal, that gets submitted to Laravel when you press the "Save" button.

The form itself consists of a text field, a textarea, a file input and a a checkbox.

The controller that is supposed to receive all the datas looks like follows for now:

```
/**
 * @param $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function postCategory($request) {
    return response()->json($request);
}
```

My goal for now is to make sure that everythings comes to the good controller's action and gets back to jQuery as JSON string. When it's done, I'll handle how the form's content should get saved.

Here is how looks my Ajax submission:

```
$("#new_category").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.origin + '/admin/categories',
        data: {
            data: $(this).serialize()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

**Update**

Here is how the form looks:

```
<form id="new_category">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nouvelle catégorie</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_title">Titre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_title" placeholder="Titre" name="category_title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="category_description" id="category_description" rows="3" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_illustration">Illustration</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="category_illustration" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category_enabled" class="form-check-input" id="category_enabled" checked="checked">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="category_enabled">Actif</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my route that handles the submission:

```
Route::post('/admin/categories', 'HomeController@postCategory');
```

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147793/laravel-ajax-call-to-controller) that helped me a lot, but I'm still getting these issues.

What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your route?

Comment: This error means - the function called expects n parameters and you have passed n-x parameters.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @adi Yes I understood what it means, but I don't understand why I get it, it's not supposed to happen (hence my question here)

Comment: What happens if you typehint the `postCategory` method in your controller as Theodore B. did?

Comment: Try changing your action as Theodor said... set the action argument as Request $request

Comment: I didn't know Javascript send a Request object like this, I'll remember next time u_u

Comment: It doesn't! Laravel expects you to add the typehint because it automagically detects extra parameters you've added yourself. This isn't always clear, but it's explained on a couple of occasions in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try editing the code to something like this:

```
/**
 * @param $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function postCategory(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that Javascript would send a Request object, I'll make sure I'll remember next time!